# gps tracking GRTQ

Tags: php, gps

I get gps data from tcp ( php socket ) but for some devices ( GRTQ ) i will get these data :
first devices sends : 
*HQ,XXXXXX,V1,time,A,**Lat**,N/S,**Lng**,W/E,000.00,000,date,FFFFFBFF,432,35,32448,33441,4#
then sends :
*HQ,XXXXXX,V9,time,A,**Lat**,N/S,**Lng**,W/E,000.10,000,date,,Caller ID,FFFFFBFF#
then sends :
$A  grQ05Ah@‘)���ÿÿûÿÿ����°#~À‚¡U

What's the meaning of this ??:
$A  grQ05Ah@‘)���ÿÿûÿÿ����°#~À‚¡U

thanks you for your help

the model of device : GRTQ

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: i want to know what is that ( and what should i reply ) because i will not get any data after the following data

Comment: Looks like something is going wrong with the charset, I fear you'll need to add some more details in order for people to give you a better (/more appropriate) answer.

Comment: but it sent the correct data before that ( what should i do ) ? what details should i add now ?

Comment: the model of device is GRTQ

Comment: I don't know enough about GRTQ or GPS to be of any help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert the received unreadable data to hexadecimal string.
You will get something like this
    24 41 20 20 67 72 51 30 35 41 68 40 2018 29 fffd fffd fffd ff ff fb ff ff fffd fffd fffd fffd b0 23 7e c0 201a a1 55

Then you can split it and parse it like this:

```
2 bytes(24),  stand for standard mode
10 bytes,  is device'ID (41 20 20 67 72)
6 bytes, is time 
6 bytes, is data
8 bytes, is latitude
2 bytes, battery like this 06= 100% 05=80% 04=60% 03=40% 02=20% 01=10%
10 bytes is  longitude

next byte C is  16 hexadecimal, 0C,  convert it into binary data, 1100 (4 bit)

Bit 3:    if is 1= East longitude  if is 0= West  longitude
Bit 2:      if is 1= North latitude,  if is 0= South latitude
Bit1:      if  is 1= A( GPS position valid) if is 0= V( gps position invalid)
Bit 0: discard

000215: 6 digits, 000 is speed (knot  1 knot =1.852 km/h )  , 215 is direction in degrees.

FFFFF9FF:vehicle_status
2 bytes :back-up data 
2 bytes  :gsm_signal
0D : （convert to decimal=13  13 means the number of satellite gps_signal)
000000034 :   mileage
4 bytes: mobile country code 
2 bytes: mnc
4 bytes: lac
4 bytes: cell_id
2 bytes: record number
```

Answer (score 0):

Chinese manufacturers/sellers call this protocol differently, but in [Traccar GPS tracking server](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar) it's known as H02 protocol. You can find documentation (unfortunately only in Chinese) [here](https://www.traccar.org/protocols/).

Basically, this communication protocol includes two types of messages: ASCII/text messages (first two of your examples) and binary messages (third example).

Comment: Thank you but what should i reply to this data to get the correct position ?

Comment: Can i avoid responding binary messages (with sms or special cmd)?

Comment: You don't need to reply to any of those messages. I don't know if can avoid binary messages. Possibly not, but you should check manual or ask manufacturer.

Comment: I check manual but it says the messages will be in hexadecimal - is this hex ?

Comment: No, messages are binary, but you can convert binary into hex string if you want.